# filling remaining space without JS

Tags: html, css

is there a way for 'fill' to fill by its height remaining space without using JS?

```
<div id="all" style="height: 30%">
<div id="ukn" style="height: unknown"></div>
<div id="fill"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: *by its height remaining space* ???

Comment: height of fill should be all.height-ukn.height.

Answer (score 2):

Simply place the unknown div inside the #fill div and set its height to 100%.

```
<div style="height:30%;">
    <div id="fill" style="height:100%;">
        <div style="height:_unknown_;"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should note in your text that you also size the `#fill` height to 100%.

Comment: I’d write *that ones* instead of *its*, as *its* can be mistaken for the *unknown* ones. Anyway, thanks for updating.

Comment: Do you know any solution without editing HTML structure just CSS?

Comment: You'll need to either update the HTML structure or use JS - since #all is a % height. If #all as a fixed height, you could just float both #fill and #unk, both other than that, I don't see any way around changing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
#fill{
min-height: 250px;
}
```

You may need to change the pixels to the height you would like.

Comment: Adjusting the `min-height` of #fill will simply cause it to be at least a specific size, not necessarily in relation to the size of #ukn.